# Programmatically turn off android:windowActionBarOverlay style from action bar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Currently, I am using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). I want to launch `SecondActivity` from `MainActivity`.

`MainActivity` is using action bar with `windowActionBarOverlay` style turned on. `SecondActivity` is using action bar with `windowActionBarOverlay` style turned off. Hence, here is how my XML looks like.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"  
    android:debuggable="false" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/ThemeWithActionBarOverlay"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".SecondActivity" 
        android:theme="@style/ThemeWithoutOverlay">
    </activity>
</application>
```

---

```
<resources>
    <style name="ThemeWithActionBarOverlay" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="abIcon">@drawable/ic_home</item>
        <item name="abTitleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarCompatTitle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeWithoutOverlay" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
        <item name="abIcon">@drawable/ic_home</item>
        <item name="abTitleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarCompatTitle</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

---

However, by doing so, in `SecondActivity`, I realize I can never have a up/back button on the top left of action bar. Although there is icon being shown, it is not pressable. Only by using back same theme (ThemeWithActionBarOverlay) as `MainActivity`, only up/back button will shown. However, if I let `SecondActivity` to use same theme as `MainActivity`, I find out no way to turn off `windowActionBarOverlay` behaviour.

```
// SecondActivity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.history_list_activity);

    ActionBar actionBar = this.getActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    // How to turn android:windowActionBarOverlay attribute to false during runtime?
    // actionBar.??? 
}
```

My questions are

1. Why the child activity has to use action bar with same theme as parent's, in order to have proper up/back button shown? Is there any way I can use different themes, yet have up/back button appears on child activity?
2. Is it possible to turn of `windowActionBarOverlay` style during runtime?

Comment: Is your second issue resolved? I am also looking for the same.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your first question, you don't need to have the parent and child activity using the same theme for the 'Up' button to work. In fact, I'm working on a similar parent/child activity application, and its working just fine using two different themes( a theme without overlay for the parent, and the fullscreen theme (with overlay) for the child).

There must be another reason why it is not working...

- Make sure you have defined **MainActivity** to be the parent of second activity. You can do that either by code, or the prefered way, in the **AndroidManifest.xml**:

  ```
  <activity
      android:name=".SecondActivity" 
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
          android:value=".MainActivity" />
  </activity>
  ```
- Make sure that in your child activity, you have activated the 'up' navigation:

  ```
   final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
   actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  ```

For your second question, try overriding the **'windowActionBarOverlay'** in the **'ThemeWithoutOverlay'** theme to **false**:

```
<style name="ThemeWithoutOverlay" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item><
    <item name="abIcon">@drawable/ic_home</item>
    <item name="abTitleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarCompatTitle</item>
</style>
```